# workflow for xpages installation

Tags: ant, workflow, xpages

I am trying to install prerequisties for workflow for xpages.I could not pass the below requirement. I installed ant, set the home pates, it works for a simple echo like "ant -build c:\test.xml"

Where is the setup folder to run "ant setup.activiti" command? it is not in ant"apache-ant-1.9.2" folder?

**Make sure Apache Ant installed in the system, go to setup folder and run command(This
will download Activiti libraries needed in our project): ant setup.activiti**

Answer (score 1):

In setup there is the build.xml file ant uses. setup.activiti is a target inside that ant file. You only need to do that when you want to <strike>mess with the source</strike> build from source / contribute